# Add a gamer timer to my program -Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, timer

I bet this has been asked before but I must be searching the wrong things because i can't find anything. I have created a simple game that gives the user simple math problems that they then must answer. I want to time how long it takes them to answer these.

So basically i want a startTimer() at the beginning of my code, and a stopTimer() at the end of my code and have the time that has elapsed be saved as a variable.

Comment: do you want to display the time or just get the time difference?

Comment: Well I am just using the console for now, so i doubt displaying the time is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want difference, use time.clock() or time.time() from the time module.

```
import time
t1 = time.clock() # or t1 = time.time()
...
t2 = time.clock() # or t2 = time.time()
elapsedTime = t2 - t1
```

Refer to https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html

Comment: this gives very strange output on linux

Comment: From the docs:
time.clock()

    On Unix, return the current processor time as a floating point number expressed in seconds. The precision, and in fact the very definition of the meaning of “processor time”, depends on that of the C function of the same name, but in any case, this is the function to use for benchmarking Python or timing algorithms.

    On Windows, this function returns wall-clock seconds elapsed since the first call to this function, as a floating point number, based on the Win32 function QueryPerformanceCounter(). The resolution is typically better than one microsecond.

Comment: This is the output from running it for a few seconds `9.4e-05`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - I don't have access to a UNIX/linux machine, so can't compare. Maybe try time.time() instead. I gather from the doc snippet above, time.clock() results on *nix systems will vary.

Answer (score 0):

```
t1 = time.time()

raw_input("enter your guess")

print("You took {} to answer".format(time.time() - t1))
```